# Difference between lookup and pattern

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In one of the questions about `RollingFileAppender` in Log4j2 I found the following piece of code `<Property name="FilePattern">C:/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM- dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz</Property>`.

I was wondering what the reason is to use a lookup `$${data:yyyy-MM}` in the first half and a pattern `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}` in the second half. What would be the effect of using for example `C:/logs/%d{yyyy-MM}/app-%d{...}-%i.log.gz`?

From what I have read in the documentation the lookup supports many - more complicated - types of property lookups, but what is the benefit in the case above especially given that the documentation explicitly states that the `filePattern` property supports date lookups (`The pattern also supports interpolation at runtime so any of the Lookups (such as the DateLookup) can be included in the pattern.`), but not going into any detail when or if that should be used.

Comment: One thing a simple experiment concluded is the following: `<Property name="arcPath">${logPath}/%d{yyyy_MM_HH_mm}</Property>` results for example for today in all files going to `logs/2018_10_00_00` whereas `<Property name="arcPath">${logPath}/$${date:yyyy_MM_HH_mm}</Property>` correctly puts files for example in `logs/2018_10_10_39` which seems weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have done some reverse engineering and the reason for the layout above is in the following code:

```
for (final ArrayPatternConverter converter : patternConverters) {
    if (converter instanceof DatePatternConverter) {
        final DatePatternConverter dateConverter = (DatePatternConverter) converter;
        frequency = calculateFrequency(dateConverter.getPattern());
    }
}
```

So in my first case the fully replaced filePattern looked like this: `logs/%d{yyyy_MM_HH_mm}/appl_log_%d{yyyy_MM_dd}.txt`

The code above from the `PatternConverter` class would pick up the first converter from `%d{yyyy_MM_HH_mm}` determine the frequency to `EVERY_MINUTE` and then later it detects the `%d{yyyy_MM_dd}` where it overwrites the old frequency of `EVERY_MINUTE` to `DAILY`. When doing a rollover it creates a pseudo log event with a time (at the start of the day because of `DAILY` frequency) to format the file time so it ends up with 00_00.

Long story short, when you use the `%` formatting the parser is using the time of the log event, which might not be the current system time when the rollover happens. When using the `$$` property lookup there is no relation to the log event therefore you always get the current time in the format you specified.